# I cannot Display MySql data in html after fetching from database fetched data can be seen in Server ( CMD )

Tags: python, django

i have tying to display data from database only by writing query in python django but i am facing some issue what cause this issue

model.py

```
class add_topic(models.Model):
    test_id=models.IntegerField() 
    topic_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)     

class Meta:
    db_table = "opicc";
```

view.py

```
def addassessment(request):
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT test_id, topic_name FROM test_topic')
results=c.fetchall()
context={"topics":results}
return render(request,'add_assessment.html',context)
```

display.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Post To</label>
       <select name="event_made_for" required="" class="custom-select">
            <option>Select Whome you want to set this Event</option></select>
            {% for i in topics %}
            <option value="{{i.test_id}}">{{i.topic_name}}</option>                            
            {%endfor%} 
            </select> 
           <!--If i print that context--!>
            {topics}                         
                         
 </div>
```

output:

```
((8, 'hello'), (9, 'Antony'))
```

i am getting this values if i run the code but i cant display individual values